# Using std::optional<A> as a class member of class A

Tags: c++, c++17, stdoptional

Why isn't it possible to define a class member of type std::optional<A> in class A?

Example:

```cpp
#include <optional>

class A {
public:
    A(std::optional<A> optional = {}) : optional_(optional) { }
    ~A() = default;
private:
    std::optional<A> optional_;
};
```

Compiler error:

```
error: incomplete type 'A' used in type trait expression
   : public integral_constant<bool, __is_trivially_destructible(_Tp)> {};
                                    ^
error: incomplete type 'A' used in type trait expression
   : public integral_constant<bool, __is_constructible(_Tp, _Args...)>
                                    ^
```

Comment: When constructing an `A`, you must allocate enough memory to store all of `A`'s members.  But an `A` may contain an `A`, which may contain an `A`, which may contain an `A`... ad infinitum.  If `A` could hold a `std::optional<A>`, it would require infinite memory on the stack.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`optional<T>` requires that `T` is a complete type (and therefore has a known size). Until the class `A`'s definition is finished, `A` is an incomplete type. Hence the error.

There is no way to have any type `T` hold a member variable of type `optional<T>`, since `optional<T>` *itself* has a member variable of type `T`. You can heap-allocate an `optional<T>` (or just a `T`, since you'd be storing a pointer that could be `nullptr`).

Comment: Thanks. What's the common way to define recursive optionals in modern c++, simplest example to implement a tree? I've tried `std::unique_ptr<A>`, too, which also doesn't work. But it works with  a `std::shared_ptr<A>`.

Comment: @Yannic `std::unique_ptr<A>` for exclusive ownership. If it "doesn't work" (which is a very vague description) then post a question with those details.

Comment: @Yannic [`unique_ptr`](https://godbolt.org/z/M9Todc) example (with moving only, no copying)

Comment: Nevermind! Mixed things up and got confused, but got it now